# initialize select of foreign keys in inline form only once in django admin

Tags: django, select, foreign-keys, admin, inline

I have such models:

```
class Table(models.Model):
    table_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, blank=True, null=True)

class Row(models.Model):
    table_title = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    table = models.ManyToManyField(Table, through="TableRowRelation")
    title  = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class TableRowRelation(models.Model):
    table  = models.ForeignKey(Table)
    row = models.ForeignKey('Row', related_name='row')
    top_padding = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

And in admin i want to create relations between table and row by means of `inline` blocks

Admin:

```
class TableAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["table_name"]
    inlines = [TableRowRelationInline]

class TableRowRelationInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = TableRowRelation
    extra = 0
```

It looks like everything works right
[image]

but there is a problem with sql queries. In each inline item for its select the sql-query is called every time. but these queries are the same.
[image]
How to initialize this select in inline block only once and make only 1 sql-query?

Comment: I think it is not possible.

Comment: i think with django everything is possible :)

Comment: With django maybe yes. But this is django-admin. Django admin work in this way.